# Change the scope of search Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I have a page where I want to search for  items only in an exam sharepoint 2010 list. 
To achieve  that

- I created a search scope  called exams.
- I created a webpage page and added a search box and search results  box to it.
  I set the scope in the webpage properties to exams and set the target url to the out of the box "/search/results.aspx".

This results in issue that the search shows me all the site content. If I append the query  text &`s=examlist`. The search results on the page seems to show all the items in the site instead of refining the search results to only items from the exams list. 
It would be good if I can show the results on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

The important point while creating the scope to only search in a specific list is that:

**Scope Rule Type**:

1. Web Address: `(http://server/site)`

In Web Address select "Folder" and type the url of custom list e.g. 
`http://server:port/sites/sitename/Lists/MyCustomList`

Below sources will guide you step by step how to use Search scopes:

1. [Steps to search a specific custom list](http://mytechnicalnotes.com/2010/03/07/steps-to-search-a-specific-custom-list).
2. [Create a Search Scope for a Sharepoint 2010 List or Library](http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-search-scope-for-a-sharepoint-2010-list-or-library).

Comment: have you tried this?